# Can I find some function caller in GDB

Tags: gdb

I have 3rd party static library : "A.lib"

(I don't have source code..)

And.. "A.lib" has some function like "bool CUserQueue::Push()"

---

I would like to set **break point all** "CUserQueue::Push()" **caller**.

(Because, I debugging "Why queue are empty? Data were passed..")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a breakpoint on all calls to a function is effectively the same as breaking on function entry. You don't need a library source to put a breakpoint on function, as function entry point is a public symbol.

"break CUserQueue::Push()" should do the trick. And make sure you build your program with no optimization and debug information enabled (-O0 -g3 flags with gcc).

Comment: There are some unknown reason, my program does not call "Push()"... So, I want to find out all functions that call "Push()". I will set break point to these functions. (not "Push()" entry)

Comment: I don't think there is some shortcut to do this. You need to find all functions that call Push() by greping through source or using some kind of "find references" in IDE, then put a breakpoints on all these functions in gdb.

Comment: Oh.."Push()" is called in 3rd party lib layer. So I can't find out. Thank you.

Comment: You could disassemble the library to see where Push() is called.